# Alleged misunderstanding in using super

Tags: python, jython, jython-2.7

I'm trying to call `super` inside a subclass to extend a subclass in jython. It happened that if I didn't put the class as a subclass, nothing would happen, and everything would go smoothly.\

Instead I would like to put it in the macro class.

E.g.:

```
class Human:
    def __init__(self):
        self.name = 'Guido'
        self.head = self.createHead()

    def createHead(self):
        return self.Head(self)

    class Head(bodyParts):
        def __init__(self, human):
            super(Head, self).__init__(oldParameterOfBodyPart) #ERROR
            self.human = human
        
        def talk(self):
            return 'talking...', self.human.name
```

The error is as follows:

```
NameError: global name 'Head' is not defined
```

Whereas if I take the sub-class out this way it works.

```
class Human:
    def __init__(self):
        self.name = 'Guido'
        self.head = self.createHead()

    def createHead(self):
        return self.Head(self)

class Head(bodyParts):
    def __init__(self, human):
        super(Head, self).__init__(oldParameterOfBodyPart)
        self.human = human
        
    def talk(self):
        return 'talking...', self.human.name
```

Is there anything I miss about using super?

Comment: That's not related to super (or Jython) - `Head` is a *nested* class, so you need to do `Human.Head` to access it.

Comment: @jonrsharpe Thanks so much! That was the solution!